# Estimating meta-mathematical properties of conjectures

Tags: formal-languages, axioms, formal-proofs, meta-math

Given a formalized system of mathematics (a set of axioms and deduction rules), is it possible to estimate meta-mathematical properties of conjectures in this system such as the number of deduction steps from the axioms before attempting their proof?

Can a mathematical system have itself sufficiently analyzable structure that permits such heuristics?

It seems that, via the Curry–Howard correspondence, the general problem might be NP-complete, and proving the existence of a proof (within limits) would be likely as hard as the halting problem. So heuristics might be limited to very simple formal systems.

I'm asking this for two reasons:

- i'm wondering if mathematical intuition can be formalized
- i'm not aware of such mechanisms in automated theorem provers

tldr:

> **Given a set of proofs, is it possible to estimate the deduction distance and other properties of yet unproven statements, saving resources during the proof search?**

Comment: Can you explain your first reason for asking this a bit more?

Comment: @Bram28 If mathematicians mentally operate algorithmically and "finitely" the computational limitations of Turing Machines etc. will apply to them. If their heuristics can be formalized, automated systems could use them. If the possibility of accurate heuristics can be disproven, then this might mean that mathematicians, if they operate finitely, only "random walk"/"pattern match"/"stumble around" and have no formal/provable basis for their intuition.

Comment: "the general problem might be NP-complete" What is "the general problem"? Re: "proving the existence of a proof (within limits) would be likely as hard as the halting problem," yes: the question of whether $p$ is a theorem of $T$ is equivalent to the halting problem as soon as $T$ is *(computably axiomatizable, consistent, and)* strong enough to implement "basic arithmetic" - this is basically immediate from part of the proof of Godel's incompleteness theorem (the representability of all computable functions in $T$).

Comment: And "implement "basic arithmetic"" is a *very* weak requirement - [Robinson arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robinson_arithmetic), which can't even prove that every number is either even or odd(!), is already enough. Even for decidable theories like Euclidean geometry this problem is quite difficult (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_closed_field#Decidability_and_quantifier_elimination)). All of this points to a general negative answer to your question. However, your question is too broadly phrased to have an airtight answer.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Does "what mathematicians do/use" have these properties? Edit: Seeing your answers now, it seems that way. Feel free to point to more examples, this seems quite interesting!

Comment: @2080 Yes. See the link to Robinson arithmetic above: even extremely basic theories of arithmetic are strong enough to fall victim to Godel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question of whether $p$ is a theorem of $T$ is equivalent to the halting problem as soon as $T$ is (computably axiomatizable, consistent, and) strong enough to implement "basic arithmetic" - this is basically immediate from part of the proof of Godel's incompleteness theorem (the representability of all computable functions in $T$).

And "implement "basic arithmetic"" is a *very* weak requirement - [Robinson arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robinson_arithmetic), which can't even prove that every number is either even or odd(!), is already enough. Even for "simple" decidable theories like Euclidean geometry or arithmetic with only addition this problem is quite difficult *(see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_closed_field#Decidability_and_quantifier_elimination) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presburger_arithmetic#Properties) respectively)*.

All of this points to a general negative answer to your question. However, your question is too broadly phrased to have an airtight answer, so there's still an element of subjectivity here. But I would hazard:

> For all but the simplest systems and properties, the problem of telling whether a formula has that property with respect to that system is undecidable; and even for very simple systems and properties, this problem is almost always computationally infeasible.

Note that the Curry-Howard correspondence doesn't really play a role here: to get "lower bound" results we just need to embed computational processes in formal systems, and this is pretty easy in many situations.

Comment: Do you personally think that, due to these constraints, it will be unlikely that such heuristics will ever be used in supporting the proof search for "useful" or "interesting" conjectures? (I'm not a mathematician so I have absolutely no clue)

Comment: @2080 Not at all. Just because something is incomputable/infeasible in general doesn't mean that there aren't interesting cases where it can be solved efficiently. I think it's extremely likely that computerized proof- and conjecture-search will become important in mathematics in the future. The negative results above just indicate that we can't hope for *general* success.

Comment: If reasoning about the global properties ("geometry of proof dependencies") is difficult, there may be ways to find methods that work probabilistically (e.g. proving "the conjecture lies *probably* within this space/distance"), or locally (within a distance of a set of proofs). If you know more terms relating to this, please throw them at me so I can read more about all of this! :)

Comment: Apparrently this is a type of question considered in the field of proof complexity: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_complexity