# Are there projects that visualize how proofs relate to each other (similar to what the Paperscape Project does for publications)?

Tags: soft-question, visualization, meta-math

The [Mathematics Genealogy Project](https://genealogy.math.ndsu.nodak.edu/) lists mentoring relationships between mathematicians, the [Paperscape Project](https://paperscape.org/) visualizes which publications are "close" to each other (by analyzing citations and coauthor relations).

> Are there similar projects concerning *proofs* and how they relate to each other?

Visualizations of the "landscape" of mathematical results and their dependencies.

Comment: How do you propose to quantify how close two proofs are to each other?

Comment: By analyzing proof dependency graphs (which are dependent on the choice of a formal system). Here is the graph for "2+2=4" in the Metamath database for example: https://twitter.com/dd4ta/status/1050433711416721408 :)

Many recent or high-level results have not been formalized yet, and are not included in such databases, so perhaps there are resources for that, too.

Comment: @RobertIsrael. I wonder if you can get very precise with this by looking at exactly which axioms are required for the argument. If two arguments use the exact same assumptions we can say they have a distance of $0$.

Comment: @Mason Regarding distance, I recently asked this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3477810/estimating-meta-mathematical-properties-of-conjectures which may interest you

Comment: @Mason You may be interested in [reverse mathematics](http://www.personal.psu.edu/t20/sosoa/chapter1.pdf).